# How can I dynamically resize a select2 input to be the same width as the selected option?

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm building a 'natural language' search form using a series of inline select inputs, using jQuery Select2 for styling. The widths of the Select2 inputs appear to be set to the width of the selected option on initialisation, which is great. I just can't work out how to get the width to update when the selected option is changed. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 54):

Try to add this to yor CSS file:

```
.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

It solved my resize problems with select2

(Edited: I do not use placeholders)

Comment: its set only container width, but if you have placeholder - it will by cut

Comment: this one fixes Bootstap 3 issues

Comment: Such a simple fix =)

Comment: It is better done without use of !important:


.select2-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

And since the problem is usually Select2 being too wide, only max-width will be sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

You can use window resize function.

Example:

```
// Fix select2 width
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.form-group').each(function() {
        var formGroup = $(this),
            formgroupWidth = formGroup.outerWidth();
        
        formGroup.find('.select2-container').css('width', formgroupWidth);
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was trying to do – I needed it to resize when changing the selected option, not on window resize. In the end I couldn't find a working solution so didn't use Select2.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post However, I had an issue when I used NMC's code.

As I can't comment on his answer, after using his code I had some annoying scrollbars appearing after using the select2 dropdowns, to fix this I used width auto instead.

```
.select2-container {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do something like this for a site

```
$(e).on("select2:closing", function(e) {
    if (e.hasOwnProperty('params') &&
        e.params.hasOwnProperty('args') && 
        e.params.args.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent') && 
        e.params.args.originalEvent.hasOwnProperty('target')) {
            var newWidth = $(e.params.args.originalEvent.target).width();
            var id = $(e.params.args.originalEvent.target).attr('id');
            var container = $("span[aria-labelledby=\""+id.split("-result")[0]+"-container"+"\"]");
            $(container).parents('span.select2').width(newWidth + 21);
    }
});
```

This is probably not fool-proof and is tied to the current API. But it gets the width of the element in the dropdown before the dropdown closes and then applies that to the container.

One thing of note, you may need to float the dropdown items to get their real size.

```
.select2-results__option {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.select2-search__field').attr('style','width:auto');

$('.select2-search__field[placeholder=""]').attr('style','width:10px');
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically resize a select2 you can use `width: 'style'` option as below:

```
$('#field_'+field.name).select2({
    placeholder: "select a option...",
    maximumSelectionLength: 1000 , 
    allowClear: true,
    ...
    width: 'style',
    data: data
});
```

And next you have to use `style="width:100%;"` as attribute for your select tag.

```
<select class="input-element-item fontsize13" id="select2" style="width:100%;" >
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For other than problems of responsive width, read the documentation of Select2. Everything is explained.

https://select2.org/appearance#container-width

```
<select class="js-example-responsive" style="width: 50%"></select>

$(".js-example-responsive").select2({
   width: 'resolve' // need to override the changed default
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give width to the select's parent element on percentage you want, and then give

$('mySelect2').select2({
width: "inherit"
.....
})